# How to create a Server Socket to which only a specific IP can connect

Tags: java, sockets, connection, serversocket

Is it possible to create a ServerSocket where instead of using the ServerSocket#[accept](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--) method for any connection, the ServerSocket waits and accepts a connection only from a specific IP?

Or, alternatively, is it possible to know the IP of a connection before accepting it so that I can reject it if it is not from that specific IP?

Comment: You can create a firewall that rejects connections from origins you don't allow. How firewalls are created and configured depends on the operating system. Do you run the program on Linux, Mac or Windows?

Comment: Hi, that would be an idea and thanks for proposing it, but are you sure that activating a firewall on the whole system for just that step of the program makes sense?

Anyway I am on Linux but for the program I would like to preserve compatibility with all 3 operating systems...

Comment: Setting up a firewall is the only way to do this. On Linux at least, the "firewall" (iptables) is always running anyway, since it's part of the kernel, you only need to add one rule to it. I'm not familiar with the other OSs.

Comment: I see, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The underlying communication stack does not support such a thing for TCP sockets.

The accept call itself returns a socket which can then be queried for the remote IP address.  You can then immediately close the socket if the IP is not to your liking.

(By the way, what you accept is a 'connection', not a 'socket'. The socket is merely a local data structure, one at each endpoint; the socket is created on your machine in response to accepting a connection. It's the difference between your telephone and the conversation with the person at the other end.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question and for pointing out the difference between "connection" and "socket", I have corrected. I had already thought about the possibility of being able to close it after accepting it, but I was wondering if I could directly save myself from accepting an unwanted connection.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely on the source IP, as it is easy to send TCP/IP packets with the same IP from another host, see [IP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing). You need to use SSL sockets and some authentication over it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a lot of experience with ServerSocket in specific, but have some with TCP sockets. I do not think this is possible, however what you can do is verify the IP address after an accept (both TCP and UDP sockets receive the IP of the other machine, since it is necessary to provide a response).

I do not see the reason you would do this (especially considering that IPs, usually, change dynamically over time for many reasons) and if there is another way to solve the problem you have.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question, in my program I need to create a Server for a certain client whose IP I know in advance (to receive a file from him) and for security reasons I would like to avoid the case where someone else can precede it and connect to the ServerSocket.

Comment: IPs should not be used to verify an entity of a computer (or a user) in a real-life scenario. But if you want to do that, you have to accept the request, verify the IP, close if it is not the IP you want and accept again. Keep this loop until an error occurs or the IP connects.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in java, but in c or python it is possible. With level 3 raw socket, you can prevent a connection, by responding `SYN` packets with `RST` packet, before accepting it.